# Determining if two codes are equivalent from their generator matrices alone

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

$C$ is an $F_3-[5, 2, 3]$ code with generator matrix

$G = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2\\2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$

Which of the following matrices is the generator matrix of a ternary code that is equivalent to $C$?

$G_a = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$

$G_b = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2\\0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

From what I understood, if by applying some monomial transformation to a generator matrix $G'$ you could obtain $G$, then the codes generated by those two matrices are equivalent. In other words, if I could perform permutations of the columns, and multiply the columns by non-zero scalar, of $G_a$ or $G_b$ to transform either into $G$, then the corresponding codes are equivalent.

I cannot seem to find any such transformation from either $G_a$ or $G_b$ to $G$, but one of their codes definitely is equivalent to that of $G$.

---

Using permutations of columns and multiplying columns by non-zeros scalars, I can get $G_a$ to

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2\\2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$

Can I then subtract col3 from col4 to get $col4 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ then add to it col 2 which would then be equal to $G$? (In other words - can I replace col4 with col2?)

Comment: "perform permutations of the columns, and multiply the columns by non-zero scalar"  you can also replace a row by a linear combination of them

Comment: @leonbloy So I can perform any ERO to $G_a$ and $G_b$ to get them to equal $G$? I tried that too and was able to get them both to equal $G$, unless I made some mistake

Comment: I think so. 
http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~pas/code/part6.pdf 
You could edit the question to add your result, so we can check it.

Comment: @leonbloy I have edited my question to show how I got from $G_a$ to $G$

Comment: You can do ERO with the rows. With the columns, you can only permutate them (and you should understand why)